# PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some data that I loop through to build a dataframe (using concat) and when I hit about the 100th iteration, I start seeing this message.  What is funny is it lists the offending code, which is already using the method it recommends (concat).  Now I do use concat in every iteration.  Should I be using concat at the end of all iterations (just one time)?  If so, how do I join the data within the iterations?

```
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  
This is usually the  result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  
Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. 
To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
df[idx] = pd.concat([FileNameSeries, BlankCellSeries, FormulaSeries, arrSeries])
```